# What is the better way to reload a part of the view with new data in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Currently, I have many tables in my view. For the first time, I am loading it with the Model property values in HTML.

But I have to reload the tables based on the change in a dropdown box. For that, I am making an ajax call and with the new data, I am replacing the table in the client side(Javascript).

Now, I wish to know, Is there any other better way to do this functionality? Like Asp.Net engine itself takes care of loading that particular table with new data, so that I don't want to recreate the html structure in JS.

Will the partial views help me in this case?

Comment: Yes, you can use `Partial View`'s, https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/partial-view-in-asp.net-mvc.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the full answer, just an idea on what you could do:

Create controller

```
public class RenderPartialController
{
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult RenderPartial(string viewName, string data)
  {
    //do something with data
    //create model for that view
    return View(viewName, model);
  }
}
```

Then in js you can make ajax call and replace html with data from response

```
function updatePartial(viewName, dataObject, selector){
  let data = JSON.stringify(dataObject); 

  $.get(`...RenderPartial?viewName=${viewName}&data=${data}`, res => {
    $(selector).html($(res).find(selector).html());
  });
}

updatePartial('_TableView', {id: 1}, '#mainTable');
```

Please remember, that if you had any JS bindings in the old html, they will be removed and you will need to reapply them.

That is just an idea, not the solution